# What are the differences between Castle Windsor 1.0 RC3 and Castle Windsor 2.0?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I've been reading a bunch and playing around with Castle Windsor 1.0 RC3 lately and really like the functionality it provides. Recently 2.0 was released but for the time being I'm pretty much stuck with RC3 for the next little while. So with that in mind what are some of the glaring differences between the two versions and what are some of the pitfalls and respective workarounds when using 1.0 RC3 over 2.0? And additionally do any of these differences/pitfalls directly influence integration with MonoRail 1.0 RC3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windsor has been improved a lot since RC3, you can see the entire [changelog here](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/InversionOfControl/trunk/src/Changes.txt).

I didn't have much trouble upgrading Windsor itself from RC3 to 2.0 in a couple of apps.

But in some other projects with RC3 I have lots of other Castle dependencies (MonoRail, ActiveRecord, ActiveRecord facility, AutomaticTransactionManagement facility) so I would have to upgrade all of them (which aren't released yet) plus I'd have to upgrade NHibernate (RC3 uses NHibernate 1.2, trunk is using NHibernate 2.1 which also isn't released yet). I even used AspectSharp which is now defunct so I'd have to replace it. Some are pretty big projects and it would take me a lot of time to upgrade all these dependencies, time that I don't have right now...

So I'll wait for all of these dependencies to release, then upgrade everything. In the meantime, RC3 works just fine...

Comment: Thanks for the changelog link. Is there anything particularly significant between the two such as performance gains or resolving improvements? I'm sure the changelog goes into detail but I'm looking for a summary of some of the bigger improvements.

Comment: The changelog *is* a summary. Perhaps the most visible change is the fluent API, but also a lot of useful extension points have been added.

Comment: fluent API: http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=250 http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=253

Comment: some new extensions points: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/05/windsor-ihandlerselector.aspx http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/05/windsor-imodelinterceptersselector.aspx

Comment: the changelog link is a 404 now. Is this kept elsewhere?